# Lazy-load feature is not removing/disabling

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading, elementor, pagespeed, disable

Lazy-load feature is not removing/disabling from the core on my Elementor Website.

I have tried theme deactivation, plugins deactivation and

```
1
add_filter('wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false');

2
function disable_lazy_load_featured_images($attr, $attachment = null) {
    $attr['loading'] = 'eager';
    return $attr;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'disable_lazy_load_featured_images');

3
function disable_elementor_lazy_loading() {
    if ( ! class_exists( 'Elementor\Frontend' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // Disable Elementor's default lazy-loading feature
    remove_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', [ 'Elementor\Frontend', 'enqueue_widgets_scripts' ] );
}
add_action( 'elementor/frontend/after_register_scripts', 'disable_elementor_lazy_loading', 999 );
```

these code snippets. But none of them worked. As well as I have tried this "Disable Lazy load" plugin. It didn't work.

Only this

```
function disable_wordpress_lazy_loading() {
    echo '<script>document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {var lazyImages = document.querySelectorAll("img[loading=\"lazy\"]");lazyImages.forEach(function(img) {img.removeAttribute("loading");});});</script>';
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'disable_wordpress_lazy_loading');
```

snippet worked.

My problem is, I want to disable/remove the lazy-load feature from the core of my Elementor website rather than modifying the HTML attribute.